# Trying to create a folder and cp the file using text file

Tags: bash, directory, cp

I'm trying to create a folder using txt file and copy the file. I have two file types:

**try.txt**

```
Changes/EMAIL/header-20-percent-off.gif
Changes/EMAIL/header-50-percent-off.gif
```

**demo of folder named zip2**

```
 zip2/EMAIL/header-20-percent-off.gif
 zip2/EMAIL/header-50-percent-off.gif
```

**Code:**

```
mkdir -p dirname `xargs -a try.txt`
cp -R  {Dont know how this will work :( }
```

**Actual output:**

```
Changes/EMAIL/header-20-percent-off.gif/
             /header-50-percent-off.gif/
```

**Expected output:**

```
Changes/EMAIL/header-20-percent-off.gif
             /header-50-percent-off.gif
```

As you can see for some reason it thinks `header-20-percent-off.gif` and `header-50-percent-off.gif` are directories.

Once `Changes/Email/` is created I would like to copy the two gif files `header-20-percent-off.gif` and `header-50-percent-off.gif` there.

Comment: I don't follow. Where to are you trying to copy the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create folders:

```
<try.txt xargs -d$'\n' dirname | xargs -d$'\n' mkdir -p
```

Then copy files. First prepare the stream with proper source and destination directories with `sed` and then pass to `xargs`:

```
sed 's@^Changes/\(.*\)@zip2/\1\n&@' try.txt |
xargs -d$'\n' -n2 cp
```

But if you are not proficient in `bash`, just read the stream line by line:

```
while IFS= read -r dest; do
   dir=$(dirname "$dest")
   mkdir -p "$dir"
   src=$(sed 's@^Changes@zip2@' <<<"$dest")
   cp "$src" "$dest"
done < try.txt
```

Don't use backticks `, they are highly discouraged. Use `$(...)` for command substitution instead.

Just doing `xargs -a try.txt` without a command makes little sense, just  `$(cat try.txt)` or better `$(<try.txt)`.

Use `-t` option with `xargs` to see what is it doing.

Explicitly specify the delimeter with `xargs -d$'\n'` - otherwise `xargs` will parse `"` `'` and `\` specially.

I believe with some luck and work you could just use `rsync` with something along `rsync --include-from=try.txt changes/ zip2/`.

Comment: Hey KamilCuk thanks for your assist. I kind of messed up my question. txt file should be zip2/EMAIL/header-20-percent-off.gif. Instead of Changes zip2/EMAIL/header-20-percent-off.gif. Is there a way i can change txt so i have Changes zip2/EMAIL/header-20-percent-off.gif . If i can get that then your code works perfectly like i have asked . Its my fault

Comment: Well, replace `Changes` with `zip2` and `zip2` with `Changes` ; ) The only part that cares is `sed 's@^Changes@zip2@'`.

Comment: <try.txt xargs -d$'\n' dirname | xargs -d$'\n' mkdir -p
I wont be able to create that directory because the data inside my txt file is zip2/EMAIL/header-20-percent-off.gif.

Comment: zip2 folder is already created with all that files . If you understand xD. I made hella complicated ..mb lmao

Comment: No, I do not understand. If you want to create Changes/... instead of zip2/... so change the prefix on lines with `sed 's@^zip2@Changes@'`

Comment: I want to change my txt file data to "Changes" from "zip2" . I want output in my text file should look like Changes/EMAIL/header-20-percent-off.gif
Changes/EMAIL/header-50-percent-off.gif FROM zip2/EMAIL/header-20-percent-off.gif
zip2/EMAIL/header-50-percent-off.gif

Comment: Remember i said i made a mistake typing txt file code . It shouldve been zip2/EMAIL/header-20-percent-off.gif
zip2/EMAIL/header-50-percent-off.gif

Comment: `I want to change my txt file data to "Changes" from "zip2"` Yes, I know. `sed 's@^zip2@Changes@'`

Comment: <try.txt xargs -d$'\n' dirname | xargs -d$'\n' mkdir -p this line wont work :( . sorry i am just a beginner on this

Comment: I guess you'll want `sed 's@^zip2@Changes@' try.txt | xargs dirname | xargs -t  mkdir`. The unix philosophy is one tool does one job. You just connect them.

Comment: $ sed 's@^zip2@Changes@' try.txt | xargs -d$'\n' dirname | xargs -t -d$'\n' mkdir
mkdir Changes/EMAIL
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Changes/EMAIL’: No such file or directory
nope :(

Comment: It's `mkdir -p`. My typo. See `man mkdir`. So it would be `sed 's@^zip2@Changes@' try.txt | xargs -d$'\n' dirname | xargs -t -d$'\n' mkdir -p`.

Comment: Last one more question to clean up my code sorry and really appreciate ur help :) . **zip2/EMAIL/header-20-percent-off.gif. is my txt file data .  is there one line command to change "zip2" to "Changes" and delete the star "*" at start . i have two sed command to do that right now . if i can do that then i can run ur original comment

Comment: i have this code rn sed 's/^\*//' difference.txt > try.txt

Comment: `*` is special in sed, see [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended). Escape it. `sed 's/^zip2\*//'`